# Install Visual Studio 2015 on mac

Tags: macos, installation, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to install Visual Studio 2015 on a mac?
Is there any straightforward documentation or explanation how to do it?

Comment: Sure - just install a Windows VM first, e.g. VMware Fusion ($) or Virtual Box (free).

Comment: As Paul R said. I used to use Virtual Box but the experiences I made weren't that good. The virtual mashine crashed quite often. But this might also be due to some wrong settings and I never read the log-files. In general VirtualBox was easy to manage and I enjoyed it when it was working.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, is there any reliable document?

Comment: You don't really need a "document". The steps are: (1) install VMware Fusion, (2) set up a VM and install Windows, (3) install Visual Studio on Windows VM.

Comment: Or use Bootcamp or use Parallels Desktop. Basically any of the existing solutions to run Windows on a Mac. Then run Visual Studio on that version of Windows.

Comment: I have windows file on my mac
1. Is it possible from the virtual box to get the installation from those files?
2. Should it be iso file ?
Thanks

Comment: Note that installing in a virtual machine you won't be able to run the Windows Phone emulator as it requires access to Hyper-V which is already used by the VM visualization,

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, [Visual Studio for Mac (preview)](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/) is available. If you are trying to install it to a location other than the internal hard drive, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41071228/2228353) (wasn't possible at that time).

Answer (score 0):

Up to this point, it's not possible to access directly Visual Studio 2015 in Mac. 
You need to use Virtual Machine and install Windows 10 along with Visual Studio 2015 and access it from there. That's the only solution at this point.

However, there's Visual Studio 2017 for Mac ->
[Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)