# Visual Studio for Mac - Install location

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2015

I am considering installing [Visual Studio (VS) for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/) on my Macbook Pro. Since my internal hard drive is short on space, I was wondering if the installer allows the user to specify an installation path? I've heard the total installation size is approximately 4 GB and so I would prefer to install VS, and *all* dependencies, to my large USB flash drive.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try it, I suppose.  IIRC, VS lets you choose the install location of some things but not all things.  The best bet, I reckon, would be to give it a bash yourself and then try moving things around to suit you.  Then answer your own question here.

Comment: By the way - if you're hoping for something as polished as Xcode, or for something as polished as, and compatible with, Visual Studio for Windows then you're out of luck. VS for Mac isn't just the IDE of last resort, it's the IDE of sheer desperation in my limited experience.  I'm sure that the final version will be better.

Comment: So sorry for the thread revival...VS for Mac will install to wherever your home folder is located. I have moved my home folder to my secondary hdd after installing a SSD. I followed the following instructions: <http://www.macworld.com/article/1164891/mac-apps/keeping-mac-os-and-data-on-separate-drives.html>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my question, even though the Visual Studio for Mac installer seems to provide the option to specify an installation path:

[image]

...after the installation, only ~170MB was written to the USB drive. The rest was written to the internal hard drive.

Fail.

Comment: Installer has no such screen anymore, no way to select location.